How can I add a timestamp to MQTT messages in AWS IoT Bridge or EMQX?
I have an AWS Greengrass device which is running two MQTT components:

aws.greengrass.clientdevices.mqtt.EMQX
aws.greengrass.clientdevices.mqtt.Bridge

I've got a hardware device which publishes MQTT updates every 5 minutes to a topic on the EMQX broker. The "mqtt.Bridge" is also subscribed to this topic so receives these messages and sends them to IoT Core.
The hardware device doesn't include a timestamp in the messages being sent to the MQTT Broker. This means that if my Greengrass device is offline, when it reconnects and sends the queued MQTT messages to IoT core, I don't know when these messages were originally sent.
Is there any mechanism in mqtt.EMQX or mqtt.Bridge for adding timestamps to messages? Or is my only option to deploy a custom component which subscribes to the MQTT topic, receives messages, adds a timestamp, and publishes a new message on a different topic which I can then route to IoT core?

There is no where in a MQTTv3 message to store a timestamp other than the payload.
If the broker supports MQTTv5 then a timestamp could be added as a Message property, without changing the payload (MQTTv5 properties will be dropped if sent to the v3 broker)
It appears that the AWS IoT broker support properties
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html#mqtt5-properties
I'm not too familiar with EMQX but I see it supports plugins, which may be able to add at timestamp property before it forwards the message to AWS.
